# Notebook booting for installing linux

Tags: linux, boot-loader

Hi I don't know if this is the correct place to ask this. My problem is that I have set the boot order in order to boot my dvd unit first, in order to install lunix, but my Notebooks just start with windows 10 directly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it boot from the drive if you insert a different bootable medium (e.g. a Windows DVD)? Is the medium readable in Windows? Did you burn the ISO as "image file"?

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is an ISO file. I'm gonna try that, thanks for answering